# Downgrade from OSX Sierra 10.12.1 Beta to OSX Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos

I Installed OSX Sierra 10.12.1 Developer Beta on my mac, and I now want to move to the official (non-beta) version of OSX Sierra.

Can I do this without a time machine backup, or wiping everything on the hard drive?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do a complete erase and reinstall. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7703247?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @DrZoo Apple provides documentation for this https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/restore#macos

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Remove yourself from the beta program, and wait for Apple to officially release 12.1, in which you will update from the App Store and be moved back to the official release. Go to **System Preferences** > **App Store**. In there you will see a section stating you are enrolled in beta software. Hit `Change` and un-enroll yourself from the beta program.
2. Use a time machine backup. You can do this by booting into Recovery Mode. You can enter that by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on startup.

[image]

3. Reinstall your OS from the same menu mentioned above, using Recovery Mode.

Apple provides some documentation for this, if you want to read a bit more detail, [check this out](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/restore#macos).